# ElasticSearch aggregation on large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch, aggregation

I use Python ElasticSearch API.
I have a dataset too large to retrieve using search().
I can retrieve it with helpers.scan() but the data is too big to be process rapidly with pandas.

So I learnt how to do aggregations to compact the data with ElasticSearch but still using search() I can't retrieve all the data. I understand that the aggregation is done on the "usual" search size, even if the aggregation would give one line ?

Finally I tried aggregations + scan or scroll but I understand that scan() or scroll() can not be used to do aggregations because those requests work on subset of the dataset then the aggregation is nonsense on the subsets.

What is the good way to do aggregations on a very large dataset ?
I can't find any relevant solution on the web.

To be more explicit my case is:
I have X thousands moving sensors transmitting every hour the last stop location, the new stop location. The move from last stop to new stop can take days, so during days I don't have relevant informations with the hourly acquisitions.
As an ElasticSearch search output I only need every unique line of the format :
sensor_id / last_stop / new_stop

Comment: What is it exactly that you're interested in? Aggregating by the sensor ids then what? Or do you just want to retrieve everything and load it into pandas?

Comment: I only need to know, for each sensor, the unique combination of last_stop / mew_stop.
Because I think it is easier to retrieve this than retrieve everything then process the data with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using elastic with pandas, you could try [eland](https://github.com/elastic/eland) a new official elastic library written to integrate better them. Try:

```
es = Elasticsearch() 

body = {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "getAllSensorId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "sensor_id",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "getAllTheLastStop": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "last_stop",
            "size": 10000
          },
      "aggs": {
        "getAllTheNewStop": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "new_stop",
            "size": 10000
          }
        }
      }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
list_of_results = []
result = es.search(index="my_index", body=body)
for sensor in result["aggregations"]["getAllTheSensorId"]["buckets"]:
    for last in sensor["getAllTheLastStop"]["buckets"]:
        for new in last["getAllTheNewStop"]["buckets"]:
            record = {"sensor": sensor['key'], "last_stop": last['key'], "new_stop": new['key']}
            list_of_results.append(record)
```

Comment: Thank you for the details, it helps a lot to add the size param in the aggs query.
So I understand that the first "size" tells how many documents you get before the aggregations, and the "size" parameter in aggs fields tells how many buckets you get after aggregation right ?
Even with size=0 at the beginning are we limited to 10,000 documents to process ?

Comment: Every aggregation is over a query result, on a set of documents. If you don't specify any query by default elasticsearch execute a match_all query. So the first size param means to return a list of size 0 from the match_all query, so you will see in the result only the aggs.

Comment: No 10.000 to process is a limit for a query, so yes you can process 10.000 fat once. For an agg there is a default limit of 10.000 buckets, so 10.000 values for that field https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html#search-settings-max-buckets Anyway, does this snippet solve your problem?

Comment: have a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html